# Character would not move up

Tags: controller, controls, character

I've made a character controller that controls a little ship that flies around based on the sample controller script found in flash but for some reason the character would not move up.

Here's the 4 direction script.

And before anyone asks IT DIDN'T RETURN ANY ERRORS OR PROBLEMS.

It just would not move upwards.

```
function fl_MoveInDirectionOfKey(event:Event) 
{
    if(this.y > 10 ) 
    {
        if (upPressed)
        {
            movePlayerUp();
            if(focus==true) 
            {
            this.y -= 5;
            //lasers.y -=5;
            }
            else 
            {
                player.y -= 11;
            }
        }
    }
    if(this.y < 710)
    {
        if (downPressed)
        {
            movePlayerDown();
            if(focus==true)
            {
                this.y +=5;
            }
            else
            {
                this.y +=11;
            }
        }
    }
    if(this.x > 5)
    {
        if(leftPressed)
        {
            movePlayerReverse();
            if(focus==true)
            {
                this.x -=5;
            }
            else
            {
                this.x -=11;
            }
        }
    }
    if(this.x < 900)
    {
        if(rightPressed)
        {
            movePlayerForward();
            if(focus==true)
            {
                this.x +=5;
            }
            else
            {
                this.x +=11;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the function is ever being called? Is the script attached to the ship?

Add some trace statements and then see what parts of the code are being reached:

```
trace("we got here");
```

Comment: this is the update function hence the event:Event and that only upward movement is blocked all other directions work as intended update i traced all parts and it seems all of it is being called but just that the object would not move upwards

Comment: So moving down works? What happens when you just do `this.y -= 5` without checking for upPressed? Maybe there's something wrong with upPressed.

Comment: it moves up but jumps around a bit then my flash crashes

Comment: Okay, so upPressed doesn't work, and putting `this.y -= 5` outside of the `if (upPressed)` conditional leads to a crash. How is upPressed defined?

Comment: fl keybutton press function that includes a check for button down and button up

Comment: Could you add the body of that function? From what you're describing it sounds like that's where the problem lies.

Comment: nope still doesnt work
its just upward movement thats not working and the code is the same for all of them

Comment: I was asking to see the body of the upPressed function because it sounds like that doesn't work.

Comment: function fl_SetKeyPressed(event:KeyboardEvent):void
  {
   switch (event.keyCode)
   {
    case Keyboard.UP:
    {
     upPressed = true;
     break;
    }
    case Keyboard.DOWN:
    {
     downPressed = true;
     break;
    }
    case Keyboard.LEFT:
    {
     leftPressed = true;
     break;
    }
    case Keyboard.RIGHT:
    {
     rightPressed = true;
     break;
    }
    case Keyboard.SHIFT:
    {
     focus = true;
     break;
    }
    case Keyboard.Z:
    {
     zPressed = true;
     break;
    }
   }
  }

Comment: What is the body of `movePlayerUp();`? I need all of the code that is modifying the position in order to determine where the problem is.